# Edit Data using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get data in form usin ajax

So I'm using the following code :

```
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  
 
   $('#form_result').html('');
  $.ajax({
  
url:"castingss/"+id+"/edit",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(html){
    $('#casting_name').val(html.data.casting_name);
    $('#casting_cin').val(html.data.casting_cin);
     $('#casting_email').val(html.data.casting_email);
    $('#casting_phone').val(html.data.casting_phone);
     $('#casting_age').val(html.data.casting_age);
    $('#casting_sexe').val(html.data.casting_sexe);
     $('#casting_city').val(html.data.casting_city);
    $('#casting_address').val(html.data.casting_address);
    $('#store_image').html("<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/images/" + html.data.casting_photo + " width='70' class='img-thumbnail' />");
    $('#store_image').append("<input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' value='"+html.data.casting_photo+"' />");
    $('#hidden_id').val(html.data.id);
    $('.modal-title').text("Edit New Record");
    $('#action_button').val("Edit");
    $('#action').val("Edit");
    $('#formModal').modal('show');
   }
  })
 });
```

When I execute I get this exception :

```
  "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
```

I understood that the url is undefind , how can I sove this problem ?

**EDIT**

I was following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.webslesson.info/2019/04/laravel-58-ajax-crud-tutorial-using-datatables.html)

they don't define a route for this URL

**EDIT2**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

//auth route for both 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { 
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

// for Manager de filial
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:manager_de_filiale']], function() { 
    Route::get('/dashboard/myprofile', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@myprofile')->name('dashboard.myprofile');
});

// for AccountManager
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:account_manager']], function() { 
    Route::get('/dashboard/postcreate', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@postcreate')->name('dashboard.postcreate');
});



Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { 
    Route::get('/castings', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@casting')->name('dashboard');
});

//for adding a new casting
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { 
Route::post('castingss', 'App\Http\Controllers\CastingController@store');
});




Route::get('castingss', 'App\Http\Controllers\CastingController@getdata');

Route::get('castingss', [App\Http\Controllers\CastingController::class, 'getdata'])->name('castingss.getdata');
```

My Controller:

```
      function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                        $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>';
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                        $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                        return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
       return view('Casting.castingss');

    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
         if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $data = Casting::findOrFail($id);
            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
        }
    }
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: show route for that

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: You can share your routes/web.php @melissamaya

Comment: also post blade code too so we can help you better to solve your problem

Comment: @JohnLobo please check EDIT

Comment: @melissamaya.better show your project web.php .not link .because your writing your own route names so

Comment: But in my web page I have no route with this url

Comment: @melissamaya what's resource route defined in web.php ?

Comment: There is a route with url `castingss/` but not one with url `castingss/{id}/edit`.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVE IT BY adding that to my web page :

```
Route::get('castingss/{id}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\CastingController::class, 'edit']);
```